# why microsoft visual studio doesn't let me choose my project destination?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project

My Microsoft Visual studio doesn't let me choose location and solution name of my project when I want to make a new project in C++. I've attached the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edd2M.png) which shows that I don't have the option for choosing the destination. pls help

Comment: Sorry, not reproducible. Works fine here.

Comment: What happens if you press ok?

Comment: Which edition, exactly, of Visual Studio? The icon looks like *some* flavor of 2017, but does not repro on my copy of Enterprise 2017.

Comment: My experience is that you can set the default solution parent directory under Tools->Options in the Projects and Solution group on the Locations page and also that you can set a custom directory in the project creation wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had this problem specifically, but have had other problems with Visual Studio 2017 where certain features cease to work correctly.

**NOTE**: this will cause Visual Studio to do essentially a sort of "factory reset".

1. In File Explorer, browse to
   **`"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio"`**.
2. Observe that there is a **`"15.0"`** folder, as well as several additional
   folders like **`"15.0xxxxxx"`**.
3. Keep the **`"15.0"`** folder, but delete (or rename or move if you want to
   be cautious) the other **`"15.0xxxxxx"`** folders.

Again, note that this will reset ALL of your custom settings including your login credentials for VS (but is a lot more convenient and faster than reinstalling).

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, not sure what was the reason but the setting changed and now I can choose my project directory.