# Visual Studio 2019 IntelliSense changed (how to get prior behavior?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Since I switched to VS 2019 (from 2017) I am pretty sure I got a degraded IntelliSense experience. I looked for settings under Tools -> Options... but did not find anything helpful.

The matter is this: suppose I have a variable kvp that has a property Key, I could type "key.", scroll to the "Key" property (if this is not already selected) and then type ";" to complete the statement.

But this does not work anymore. Instead it now ignores what I selected and I get

key.;

The only way to get the selected property is to explicitly hit enter. Same when I type the first character(s) to select the desired option: when pressing ; it just leaves what I already typed and adds the ; immediately behind it, ignoring what I selected in the popup menu.

What happened and how do I get the proper behavior back?

I am using the Preview version but I already had a couple of updates and it does not improve so I guess it is by design or default behavior now.

Here's some of my code for Perry. It is just an example though, the problem (or what I regard to be a problem) occurs with any object variable.

```
private static void AddBlockNodes(TreeNode node, IDictionary<string, Block> blocks)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Block> kvp in blocks)
    {
        string name = kvp.Key;
        Block block = kvp.Value;

        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(name);
        childNode.Tag = block;

        node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        AddBlockNodes(childNode, block.Subblocks);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a universal rule in CS world - try uninstalling and installing :)

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible sample with us?

Comment: @Perry I described the issue in my question. What more would you like to see? I am on Version 16.6.0 Preview 2.1 by the way (Community Preview).

Comment: @Perry I added code although I do not see how that would make it any clearer. Block is a custom class but you do not need it to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236203/6610379.  This is related to problems in VS 2017, but you may be able to adapt for VS 2019 and see if it helps (short of a reinstall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it just leaves what I already typed and adds the ; immediately behind
>   it, ignoring what I selected in the popup menu.What happened and how
>   do I get the proper behavior back?

It is quite an abnormal behavior and l have installed Visual Studio 16.6.0 Preview 2.1 and test your code in my side and it works well.

Type variable `kvp.` and then select property `Key` and it types as expected. I did not face missing property `Key` during the process.

You can try these steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**Suggestion**

**1)** reset all settings by `Tools`-->`Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset all settings`

**2)** close VS Instance, enter the project path and delete `.vs` hidden folder which stores some Intellisense settings, `bin`, `obj` folder and then restart your project again. I wonder if you migrate an old project into VS2019 preview version, I think you should complete this step.

**3)** disable any third party extensions if you have under Extensions-->Manage Extensions in case they cause this behavior.

**4)** delete all component caches under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx(16.0 is VS2019)\ComponentModelCache`

**5)** try to create a new project in VS2019 Preview version and test whether this issue persists in the new platform and if it works, I think it is an issue of your project itself. Or you can try to migrate your project into the new project.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: My project was migrated (from 2017) but I created a new project and it had the same issue. Suggestion 1 and 2 made no difference. I then disabled all extensions, including "Visual Studio IntelliCode". I found after this I did not have any form of auto completion anymore. I re-enabled just this "Visual Studio IntelliCode" extension, got IntelliSense back and found it behaved normally!

Comment: It is a little different still. I do not know why I lost IntelliSense altogether at some point but here's what I can reproduce. If I disable extension "Visual Studio IntelliCode" (version 2.2.554.756) and restart VS, IntelliSense works well. If I re-enable the extension and restart VS, it breaks down again. I never installed this extension consciously, I assume it came pre-installed. But then again I may have done it and forgot about it.